# flutter google_sign_in get id token without firebase

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-signin

I looked at a lot of post related to this topic but none were able to solve my problem so here it is:
I use google_sign_in to be able to authenticate with a gmail account all without going through firebase. Everything is going well and I retrieve the user information well but the concern is that the value of my idToken is null whatever my manipulation. However, I did register my app via the google console and here is my code:

```
final GoogleSignInAccount user = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await user.authentication;
  print('======== Google auth ===========');
  print(googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken);
  print(googleSignInAuthentication.idToken);
  print('===================');
```

And here is what it returns to me:
[image]

I get the access token well but the token id is null and I would like to know:

- Is it possible to retrieve the idToken without going through firebase when you have a custom API?
- If not, in which part is the method entered to be able to retrieve this token?

Answer (score 2):

Yes You can.

I had this working long time back with PHP that would take care of the google-auth token validation.

This is with respect to  `google_sign_in: ^4.4.2`

[The Github Sample Project](https://github.com/epynic/flutter_google_sign_in_php)

1. Create a GCP project at
   https://console.cloud.google.com/projectcreate
2. Next go to https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in and select *Configure Project*, client as Android.
   Enter Package name and SHA1

#### Generating SHA1 signing certificates.

1. Execute in terminal (assign a password and some other parameters)

   `keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias androiddebugkey`
2. From the above step you will have a `key.jks` file for you.
3. In `android/app/build.gradle` under android add these settings:

   ```
   signingConfigs {
       debug {
           storeFile file('key.jks') 
           storePassword 'epynic'
           keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
           keyPassword 'epynic'
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       debug {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
       }
   }
   ```

   `storeFile file('/home/epynic/key.jks')` - path to your key file generated in step 2

   `storePassword 'epynic'` &  `keyPassword 'epynic'` the password used to generate the key in step 2.
4. In termial execute `keytool -keystore key.jks -list -v` and in the output you’ll have the SHA-1 fingerprint.
5. Find your package name at `AndroidManifest.xml` file, under the `package=` attribute.

Comment: Sorry for the response time, I have already performed these steps but unfortunately it still results in a null idtoken.

Comment: Still getting null for `idtoken` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and you need to include the serverClientId which is your Client ID for Web application in the google console as a parameter